# Bitmap object turns rgb(13,11,12) into rgb(211,211,211)?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap

Ok, this is a strange one. Huge props to the person that knows this.

I have this code, that crops part of an image, and puts it in `bmpCropped`.

```
    void CropImage()
    {
        int W = nowX - StartX;
        int H = nowY - StartY;

        if (W > 0 && H > 0)
        {
            bmpCropped = new Bitmap(W, H);
            Graphics gfxCropped = Graphics.FromImage(bmpCropped);
            gfxCropped.DrawImage(bmpOriginal, new Rectangle(0, 0, W, H), new Rectangle(StartX, StartY, W, H), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
    }
```

For some strange reason, all colors that have RGB values of R:13, G:11, B:12 are changed to R:211, G:211, B:211. Notice the DrawImage? bmpCropped is drawn on the screen, where I'm not seeing the 211,211,211 at all. But if I save the image using bmpCropped.Save(...), I am seeing the 211,211,211.

Anyone has any clues on why and how this is happening, and if I can get around this problem without changing the pixel to a different color?

Comment: What format are you saving in?

Comment: It happens with both jpg and png.

Comment: I also tried other combinations of colors, like 11,12,13, but it's really only 13,11,12. Nothing else.

Comment: What type of image is bmpOriginal?

Comment: bmpOriginal is made up from the Graphics.CopyFromScreen method.

Comment: More specifically what is the PixelFormat of the bmpOriginal? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx

Comment: This has to be caused by whatever you do *after* you call Save().  What are you using to inspect the image file?  Both jpeg and png are compressed image file formats, the byte values in the file have no correspondence at all with the pixel color.

Comment: @Hans, I've opened the saved png in Photoshop and looked at the color value using the color picker. Shows the same color in jpg/png. I assume it's something with the transparancy, but I wonder what?

Comment: Transparency?  Where did that come from?  Nothing in your snippet (nor CopyFromScreen) would create any transparency.

Comment: I don't know, perhaps CopyFromScreen returns a Format32bppArgb instead of Format32bppRgb. Odd.

Comment: Glad to see you found the answer. I figured there was a PixelFormat issue but I didn't have time to write any test code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a transparent source bitmap using a transparency key.  The background color of your destination shows through the transparent pixels.

Comment: I fixed it by making a new graphics object that made sure to have the correct PixelFormat. Thanks!